# Almost All apache VHOSTs go to the default "It Works Site"

Tags: apache-2.2, ubuntu, website

First off I am running Ubuntu 11.04.  I installed Apache through tasksel along with phpmyadmin, and mysql.  My localhost site works and I can get into phpmyadmin. I have 5 sites setup through VHOST files.  I can access 3 of them without any problems.

My problem is there are 2 other VHOSTs that I cannot access the actual site from the browser.  Instead it always shows the Default "It works" page.  These latest 2 sites are my new sites so I havnt figured this out since adding my fourth site to work on.  The first 3 sites for some reason work and I can access the sites through the browser.

Here is what my /etc/hosts file looks like.

127.0.0.1       my.dev

127.0.1.1       systemcrashed

127.0.0.1       dev.bac

127.0.0.1       vl.dev

127.0.0.1       manager.dev

127.0.0.1       pw.dev

The sites that I cannot get working are my.dev and dev.bac.  my.dev was the fourth site to add a VHOST file for and recently I just added dev.bac again to try to setup another site I need.

After creating both the VHOST files I ran a2ensite my.dev to enable the site.  I have checked the mod_rewrite for apache to see if it was enabled.  After running a2enmod rewrite, I get the message mod-rewrite is already enabled.

Here is what my VHOST for both the sites that do not work.  (Besides the paths are different)

```
<VirtualHost *:80>

    ServerName dev.back
    DocumentRoot /home/developmental/workspace/dev.bac/public

    <Directory /home/developmental/workspace/dev.bac/public>
            AllowOverride All
            Options All
            Order allow,deny
            Allow from all
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

If it makes a difference (which i don't think is does, but trying to give all relevant information) I use the Zend Framework on my projects.  So the root of any site starts in the public folder.  I have also ensured that there is an .htaccess file residing inside the public folder as well.

[Edited showing /usr/sbin/apache2ctl -S]

```
VirtualHost configuration:
wildcard NameVirtualHosts and _default_ servers:
*:80                   is a NameVirtualHost
     default server localhost (/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default:1)
     port 80 namevhost localhost (/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default:1)
     port 80 namevhost dev.bac (/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/dev.bac:1)
     port 80 namevhost manager.dev (/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/manager.dev:1)
     port 80 namevhost pw.dev (/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/pw.dev:1)
     port 80 namevhost my.dev (/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/my.dev:1)
     port 80 namevhost vl.dev (/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/vl.dev:1)
Syntax OK
```

[VHOST for my.dev]

```
<VirtualHost *:80>

    ServerName my.dev
    DocumentRoot /home/developmental/workspace/PW1/public

    <Directory /home/developmental/workspace/PW1/public>
            AllowOverride All
            Options All
            Order allow,deny
            Allow from all
    </Directory>

</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: You might get more useful answers, if you post your question to Serverfault.com. That place is more dedicated to server related questions.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Almost All apache VHOSTs go to the default "It Works Site"](http://serverfault.com/questions/317948/almost-all-apache-vhosts-go-to-the-default-it-works-site)

Comment: Show us the output of `/usr/sbin/apache2ctl -S`

Comment: Your question is a little rambling, can you edit it down?

Comment: Can you do this: tail -f the apache transfer file and then browse through those site.

Comment: I don't know what the transfer file is.  I looked at access.log, other_vhosts_access.log.  Those files show my other sites that are working and the GET requests, but I didnt see anything that shows something about dev.bac & my.dev .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know if it is typo, but in your /etc/hosts you have:

127.0.0.1 dev.bac

and in the virtual host configuration you have:

ServerName dev.back

Then, is normal that your apache redirect you to the wrong place.

Comment: I noticed that also when I ran /usr/sbin/apache2ct1 -S .  dev.bac is now working but I am still having a problem pw.dev .  I tried to look at the same things for a typo but I am not seeing anything.

Comment: could you post the configuration for the other virtual host?

Comment: I posted the VHOST for my.dev above in my original question at the bottom (I made a mistake above and said it was pw.dev wasn't working when it really is my.dev that is not working)